# wxMediaCtrl causes access read violation when loading

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I've been experiencing issues with the `wxMediaCtrl` control causing an "Access Read Violation" and some other exceptions when calling `wxMediaCtrl->Load();` I'm fairly new to wxWidgets having only built one project before this one.
This is what I am attempting:

```
Main::Main() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "MainFrame", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 500))
{
    SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(0xFAF9F6));
    m_mediaCtrl = new wxMediaCtrl(this, wxID_MEDIACTRL, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    m_mediaCtrl->Connect(wxID_MEDIACTRL, wxEVT_MEDIA_LOADED, (wxObjectEventFunction)(wxEventFunction)(wxMediaEventFunction) &Main::OnMediaLoaded);
    m_mediaCtrl->ShowPlayerControls(wxMEDIACTRLPLAYERCONTROLS_DEFAULT);
    m_mediaCtrl->Load("C:\\Users\\User\\Videos\\Video.mp4");
}

void Main::OnMediaLoaded()
{
    m_mediaCtrl->Play();
}
```

I am using Visual Studio and this is a portion of the output:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB0626CF19 in Application.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: bad_hresult at memory location 0x0000009B08AFEE30.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CompPkgSup.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Media.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\MSAudDecMFT.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AppXDeploymentClient.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\RESAMPLEDMO.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\COLORCNV.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Application.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msmpeg2vdec.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAC16BA0CD (d3d9.dll) in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000038.
```

**What I've already tried**

- Compiling examples from the documentation
- Looking through existing forums and issues
- Using `Bind();` instead of `Connect();`
- Using different architecture and configuration

**Results**
Calling `Load();` crashes the application and `OnMediaLoaded()` is never executed.

**Edit:**
I've tried compiling the sample: "mediaplayer" and this is the output:

```
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\amdihk32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown at 0x7748FA72 in mediaplayer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: bad_hresult at memory location 0x0743F5D0.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CompPkgSup.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Media.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSAudDecMFT.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AppXDeploymentClient.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RESAMPLEDMO.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\COLORCNV.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'mediaplayer.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msmpeg2vdec.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x7379CCAD (d3d9.dll) in mediaplayer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.
```

**Edit**

I copied the executable to another pc and it seams to work fine there. I’m still not sure what the problem is

**Edit**

It seams that the error starts here
[image: Error]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ***Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000038*** looks like a null pointer somewhere, possibly not related to the code that is presented in the question. ***Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB0626CF19 in Application.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: bad_hresult at memory location 0x0000009B08AFEE30.***  Is also a bit troubling. The rest about pdbs is not really an issue.

Comment: @Zpher, can you try to build the `media` sample found in the wxWidgets\samples directory and then try to load the file in question. I presume the file exist and it is readable by the user you trying to read it from.

Comment: Or try to buid the `Debug` version of the library and your application and see where the crash occur. One question though - is your application use threads? If so - do you access GUI object from a secondary thread?

Comment: I will try to build the wxWidgets\samples, and I’ll let you know the results. Also, I’ve tried multiple video files as I thought that maybe the format caused issues, and no, my application doesn’t use any threads yet

Comment: Ok, I successfully compiled the `wxWidgets` mediaplayer sample using x86 Debug and the application runs but when I try to load a video file I still get exceptions and the application crashes. Visual studio says that "d3d9.pdb" is not loaded.

Comment: @Igor I also just tried loading a url but with no luck...

Comment: ***Visual studio says that "d3d9.pdb" is not loaded*** Not a real problem. Having pdbs allow you to see inside the dll when debugging (which you will rarely want to do). You could enable the symbol server in Visual Studio but then this adds a few second delay on debugging every time.

Comment: ***I still get exceptions and the application crashes.*** Where do you get this exception? Did you let it break into the debugger, Did you switch the callstack from the dll to the code you have?

Comment: @drescherjm I am currently downloading the Microsoft Symbols. The exceptions appear in the output of Visual Studio, and since the symbols are not loaded, no debug information is available. The exception seams to be happening in a Microsoft library, d3d9.dll

Comment: My expectation is the null pointer in d3d9.dll is likely due to the previous error ***Microsoft C++ exception: bad_hresult at memory location 0x0743F5D0.***

Comment: @drescherjm ok, enabling symbols did nothing, now I get "Source Not Available", and "Exception thrown at..."

Comment: @drescherjm I added an image showing where the exception starts, this call passes execution to d3d9.dll which causes the Read Access Violation

Comment: @Zpher, please build wxWidgets as Debug and then the sample as Debug and try again. I suspect that there is a Debug/Release difference between the library and sample/your code. Remember - they BOTH ABSOLUTELY HAS TO BE BUILD WITH EXACTLY THE SAME SETTINGS. And also - how exactly did you build wxWidgets library?

Comment: @igor, I don't believe that the issue has to do with the build because I successfully ran the sample on a different Windows machine with no errors. Hence, I think there's a problem with my windows installation or configuration since the problem I'm facing only occurs on a Lenovo laptop which I am currently using. I've since given up, and I am looking for other means of playing video

Comment: @Zpher, ok. That for letting us know.